# babel causing cref mistakes to labels when compiled with htlatex

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, cleveref, htlatex

**Update**:

I'd be very interested to know what `babel` does to that enables the advanced hungarian accents to be loaded. The comments below indicate that it should really have no affect.  Given the experience and brilliance of those responding their probably right.  That being said, it is doing something as it definitely gives me a scaleable character when I use it. Since `babel` on it's own is interfering with `cleveref` I'd like to extract whatever part it's providing that character (recognizing that it's probably not changing encoding or anything) and just use that snippet.

**Summary**

- Document with `cref` and figure environments
- Custom figure environment is setup to let me build a complex paneled figure (considerable code not shown)
- The figure caption may include an enumerated list
- The overall figure label has trouble being referenced** when there is an enumerate environment in the figure caption
- The "\cref{figure}" reference is, for some reason with `htlatex` and `babel` is not being applied to the figure label, but is being recognized as the last label used in the enumerate environment
- Strangely the `\label` location in the caption doesn't matter; it can follow the list and this will still fail
- This problem does not appear following pdf compilation
- This problem only appears in htlatex when babel is used

So this MWE should compile just fine with `xelatex` it does on my computer. Unfortunately while it compiles completely with `htlatex` as well, I get a problem with the `cref` command.  I only get this problem if I include `babel`, otherwise the `htlatex`compile result is accurate as well.

In the html file, where I would expect to see (like the pdf):

> Reference: Fig. 1

Instead I see:

> Reference: item (iii)

Which tells me that somehow the environment I've created/used is using the last possible label from the enumerate.

**MWE** - Including customizations that may interfere with solution

```
%%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\documentclass[10pt, oneside, letterpaper]{article} %oneside twoside

\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,float,grffile}
\usepackage[format=hang,singlelinecheck=0,font={sf,small},labelfont=bf]{subfig}

\makeatletter
\captionsetup[subfigure]{
    subrefformat=simple,
    labelformat=simple,
    listofformat=subsimple
}%

\captionsetup[figure]{
    %labelfont={bf},
    labelformat={default},
    labelsep=period,
    name={Fig.}
}%

\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0mm,captionskip=0mm}%   

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
\makeatother    

\newcounter{HTMLalternative}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\PanelledFigure}{ O{7.0625 in} o O{1.25}}
{%% THIS WILL BREAK ENDFLOATS
    \def\ImagePanelSize{#1}%
    \def\AlternateHTMLImage{#2}
    \def\ColSepSize{#3}%
    \begin{figure}%
    \centering%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%{\textwidth}
}%      
\def\endPanelledFigure
{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{figure}%
    %\clearpage%
    \setcounter{HTMLalternative}{0}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CULPRIT LINE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,hungarian]{babel}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CULPRIT LINE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\selectlanguage{english}

    Reference:  \cref{fig:ref}

    \begin{PanelledFigure}[7.0625in][../FigureExternalization/Figure_iii.png]%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.jpg}\\%
    \caption[NO FIGURE LEGEND EXPECTED]{%
    \label{fig:ref}%
        Little figure summary here that provides extra details:  
        \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
            \item first example;
            \item another example;
            and \item last example.
        \end{enumerate*}
    }%
    \end{PanelledFigure}%
\end{document}
```

**Update**:

It looks like cleveref doesn't yet support Hungarian and this argument is actually the part that is causing problems.

So the problem is now less about `cref`, and more about how to insert complex characters such as those found in Hungarian, when compiling with htlatex. When I compile the following, I get two blurry png images inserted that needs to be worked around.

```
%%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\documentclass[10pt, oneside, letterpaper]{article} %oneside twoside

\usepackage{xparse,xpatch,letltxmacro}

\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifunicode
\ifxetex\unicodetrue\fi
\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{textcomp} % needed for degree sign or something with tex4ht
    %\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american,hungarian]{babel}

    %\selectlanguage{english}
    % No defaults to set yet

    \usepackage{alternative4ht}

    \altusepackage[T1]{fontspec}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

    \altusepackage{polyglossia}

\else
% These packages won't work in html, so only include if using the pdf generation.

    \ifxetex
        \usepackage{textgreek}
        \usepackage{polyglossia} % loads fontspec (font selection with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX - load open type fonts)
        \setmainlanguage{english}

        \setmainfont[
        Ligatures=TeX,
        SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
        SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
        ]{Times New Roman}


        %\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
        %\setmainfont[
        %Extension=.otf,
        %UprightFont= *-regular,
        %BoldFont=*-bold,
        %ItalicFont=*-italic,
        %BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
        %]{texgyreheros}

        \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \else
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        % This will likely need improvements to fonts and languages still
    \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\noindent
%\selectlanguage{english}

Text with a complex accent \H{o} or \H{u} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading `enumerate` and `enumitem`? What is the command to compile this document with `htlatex`? In my point of view you're abusing the `PanelledFigure` macro as an environment, which isn't really

Comment: Also `\usepackage[english]{cleveref}` seems to be a better way

Comment: I no longer remember why `enumerate` is being loaded, but I load `enumitem` because I need to customize the label's appearance and I found efficient solutions to customize my list aesthetics with `enumitem`.  Before updating my question with the compile info, as the compile script I wrote is very complex, but usable by, the MWE, I will do a quick a quick MWE test of common/simple htlatex compile sequences to verify this is simply reproducible.  If you tried this with your own preferred htlatex sequence and observed the failed picture import with `example-image-a.jpg` that is what I see to.

Comment: Use `enumitem`, it's the more sophisticated package (Sorry, David Carlisle ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The babel is used because I was unable to find a way, short of using it, to get a few Hungarian accents (in my bibliography) to display without appearing as a horrible png image of the accented character.

Comment: Babel has nothing to do with accents: you just have load `fontenc` with option `[T1]`, and `inputenc`, preferably with option `[utf8]`.

Comment: @Bernard: The O.P. uses `xelatex`, so `inputenc` is no good idea here, but you're right about the accents, of course

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the info, I'll try putting these into my main document, and avoid babel altogether.  I tried so many combinations of polyglossia, fontenc, inputenc, and I remember trying options like utf8 and T1, I no longer remember what I tried, but I never had much luck with that unique hungarian accented character except with babel.

Comment: @EngBIRD: You don't have to uses these extensions with `xelatex`, as Chrstian Hupfer mentioned. But an important points is that `xelatex` expects your TeX file to be utf8 encoded. So perhaps you should check whether your editor is configured to use  `utf8`. Most modern editors are, but I believe TeXshop isn't by default, for instance.

Comment: @Bernard the problems doesn't occur with xelatex, it's with `tex4ht`.  I'm also trying to avoid encoding problems by using latex commands, i.e. `\H{u}`.  I just compiled my main doucment without my babel line, and it generated `filename0x.png` which contains the accent.

Comment: @EngBird: Regardless whether `babel` is loaded or not, running `htlatex` without any options etc. with this document, I get a `Fig` reference, not `item`, as you've reported. If you run `htlatex` with other arguments, this would be useful to know

Comment: @EngBIRD: I can't test on that system who should not be named here -- I tested on Linux ;-) ... and apparently Hungarian is language that is not (yet) supported by `cleveref` internally predefined `\crefname` etc. setups.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Ok, that sounds like you've identified the crux of the matter.  Guess I need to figure out why this only works in my document with babel...  You and Bernard really know your stuff, so I hope there's a way to use this `\H{o}` character without it (babel). It doesn't crash without it, like I said before, it just inserts a horrid png of the character instead of unicode (or whatever) character.

Comment: @EngBIRD: As Bernard wrote: For the accents,  the fontencoding is much more important. I don't think that you really want to provide sections or translations in Hungarian -- removing Hungarian from the `babel` options seems to be the best solution here.

Comment: @EngBIRD: htlatex produces ő from `\H{o}` for me, scalable, no .png file.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm preparing a MWE to update the question with, but basically they center around uses of `\usepackage{alternative4ht}`
`\altusepackage[T1]{fontspec}`
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} `
`\altusepackage{polyglossia}` that I found in various answers on the site.

Comment: My system does not have a `.sty` file named `alternative4ht`. I can't check this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I got it from a previous question on this site, I forgot to save the link, I only saved the source location:  https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/blob/master/alternative4ht.sty.  If your able to produce the characters without it, perhaps this is an answer that would work for me too.  Unless it's unique to character encoding available on linux.

Comment: @EngBIRD: `htlatex` does not support `polyglossia` (due to `fontspec`), so you seem to be restricted to a `pdflatex` compilation with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Have you tried to type in the relevant Hungarian characters directly with unicode commands? I.e. ő is typed with CTRL-SHIFT 0151 on my system. I entered it your first 'MWE', after adding `inputenc` and it compiled correctly both for `.pdf ` and `htlatex`. I don't know however, whether all Hungarian letters are supported this way by `inputenc`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Because of If statements capable of detecting the compile engine I think I'm flexible to use any package(s) that will let me produce this character.  I'm quite stuck however on latex formats like `\H{o}` and `\H{u}` as the sub documents I'm given are full of these and I would be constantly updating the same files over and over as I won't be able to get my collaborators to make the change in their files to a unicode command.

Comment: @EngBIRD: How about this: Write a small package that all your collaborators can access and use such commands like `\newcommand{\otheweirdhungariancharacter}{ő}` in there. Then you can use `\otheweirdhungariancharacter` in any of the Hungarian names and no one has to remember the unicode setup. Of course, it requires typing the unicode sequence once or a copying of the character display from a website that is using it, best from a unicode table on the web

Comment: @ChristianHupfer do you know if it would be conceivable to use your approach with `\renewcommand` instead and use the accents `\H{o}` and `\H{u}` as commands/argument pairs?  My collaborators don't use LaTeX, hence why I'm trying so hard to get it into html; But for some reason they are working with bib files and bibtex exports so they are mostly compatible so I'm stuck with the latex style accents in the files they produce.  Unfortunately I can't get them to use a version controlled and/or file sharing system so we can work on the same files.

Comment: @EngBIRD: Using `\H{o}` etc. inside the a wrapper macro should work as well

Comment: @EngBIRD: `babel` is not interfering with `cleveref` -- no one has written the relevant `\crefname` etc. settings for Hungarian and various other languages so far. By default `cleveref` uses English, it has support for German, Dutch, French, Spanish, Italian, Russian, Ukrainian, Norsk, Danish, Esperanto (!), Swedish and Brazilian.

Comment: You don't need to use `alternative4ht` and it's support for `fontspec` anymore. `fontspec` is supported by `tex4ht` for some time. You only need to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX for the compilation, which isn't possible with `htlatex`. You need to use `make4ht -ul` or `make4ht -ux`. I can compile your example without issues (other than that you use `T1` option for `fontspec`, which is incorrect)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I get the same problem when trying to refer to a figure using `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` and `\usepackage[capitalize,swedish]{cleveref}`. Any idea why?

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson: Well, I have no idea about Swedish language apart from "Jag hetter Christian" ;-) but I'll take a look later on this day or tomorrow...